# RAR Usage in Linux Command Line

Tags: linux, command-line, rar

I'm using RAR 3.80 (command-line) on CentOS 5.5.

I have a .rar file called `example.rar`; if I use the following command then I can clearly see that it displays an archive comment and a list of filenames:

```
rar l example.rar

 Name             Size   Packed Ratio  Date   Time     Attr      CRC   Meth Ver
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 google.txt         72       72 100% 13-07-09 17:42  .....A.   0D3BCA05 m0g 2.0
 0001.jpg   835119   835119 100% 10-09-07 11:31  .....A.   51139B05 m0g 2.0
```

I tried to delete `google.txt` from the archive using the following command:

```
rar d example.rar google.txt
```

However it didn't work and says:

```
Deleting from example.rar
No files to delete
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

I also want to overwrite the original archive comment with my own comment. I don't know how to do this, as RAR only has a command to add an archive comment, not delete or replace an existing comment. How can I do that?

Comment: If you try "Add archive comment" when there is already a comment, does it overwrite it, barf, or fail silently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `c` command to add an archive comment, it will overwrite the archive comment that already exists, e.g.

```
rar c example.rar
```

As for deleting files from RAR archives, the syntax is definitely:

```
rar d example.rar google.txt
```

It may be possible that `google.txt` is in a subfolder inside the archive (although I would expect the subfolder itself to be listed in your included output). To see the exact filename including subfolder, use the verbose list command:

```
rar v example.rar
```

This will reveal the full path if `google.txt` is indeed inside a subfolder, e.g.

```
rar v example.rar

 Name             Size   Packed Ratio  Date   Time     Attr      CRC   Meth Ver
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 sub\google.txt         72       72 100% 13-07-09 17:42  .....A.   0D3BCA05 m0g 2.0
 0001.jpg   835119   835119 100% 10-09-07 11:31  .....A.   51139B05 m0g 2.0
```

You can then delete it by using the full path:

```
rar d example.rar sub\google.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

google.txt is likely in a subdirectory.

So to delete, it would be:

```
 rar d example.rar subdir\google.txt
```

Instead of using the 'l' command to list, use the 'v' command to 'verbosely list'.

```
 rar v example.rar
```

The subdirectory name should appear.